# How to use _construct in magento

Tags: php, magento, solr

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Working with Magento CE 1.7 & Solr 4.6.

I have some code for Solr i'm using that code so many times in my module,So i want to run this code when the page loading.

Right now i'm running this all code each and every time when i want,But i don't want to do like this.

```
<?php 
  Apache_Solr_Service('');
  // ------------
  // ------------
?>
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: heading of question and description has no relation. you need to run some code, while some page loads. to which page you are referring? be specific. Please make your question specific to particular problem so that you will get lot of help.

Comment: @programmer_rkt i found in some articles it is possible with _construct() method. thats why like & i don't have idea for this which heading matches for this. Sorry

Comment: can you say which page you are are referring to ? There is lot of pages in magento such as home page, list page, product view page, cart page etc. and can you show the links that you referencing with?

Comment: i'm trying to add this code in header file...

Comment: so you have a module and you need to insert your module in headerfile of magento. thats it?

Comment: did you set up a module for this? what is the functioning of your module? whether it use to display some data in header section of magento? please elaborate what you want to do with your module

Comment: In my module i'm getting search products if Apache Solr server is running means response from the apache or else normal magento functionality.